Anchor installation stops with error: (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill) on random crates
Today i tried installing Anchor and it was stopping on random crates with a SIGKILL error 9.
I was using this command
cargo install --git https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor --tag v0.30.0 anchor-cli --locked

Here one example of the failed installation attempts:
   Compiling equivalent v1.0.1
error: failed to run custom build command for `thiserror v1.0.58`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/var/folders/5b/rg_pzmcj1vzcf3m_d1bjrrch0000gn/T/cargo-instally3yTSo/release/build/thiserror-065f12ff8d055046/build-script-build` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to run custom build command for `semver v1.0.22`

Caused by:

      process didn't exit successfully: `/var/folders/5b/rg_pzmcj1vzcf3m_d1bjrrch0000gn/T/cargo-instally3yTSo/release/build/semver-3f88a554ab763251/build-script-build` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
    error: failed to compile `anchor-cli v0.30.0 (https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor?tag=v0.30.0#852fcc77)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/var/folders/5b/rg_pzmcj1vzcf3m_d1bjrrch0000gn/T/cargo-instally3yTSo`.

It stops on different crates though.

After some investigation I changed the PATH to a minimum like so
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/jonasmac2/.cargo/bin

With this the anchor installation ran through again. Then I step by step added things back and figured out that the binary that was breaking it was binutils which I had installed via homebrew.
After running
brew uninstall binutils 

it was also working again with all the other path variables.
Hope that helps if someone has a similar problem in the future.

This can also happen if your machine runs out of memory and the OOM killer gets the process
